# Geo Location aware Posts

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I am trying to publish a post on the user news feed with the users current location.

According to the [documentation on 'Post'](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) I need to add the location information to the 'place' attribute.

But is seems it is associated with an already defined 'place'. My requirement is to just push the lat / long info to dsiplay the city. Is this possible with the current graph API ?

Comment: Hi, are you still looking for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no public API to push a new place info, you can only pass existing "places".

Answer (score 0):

You could begin by finding the name of the current city and country by inspecting some nearby places:
[/search?type=place&center=**LAT**,**LONG**](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/346637838687298/?method=GET&path=search%3Ftype%3Dplace%26center%3D65.596586%2C22.153756)

Then you can try to find the **Place ID** of that city:
[/search?type=place&center=**LAT**,**LONG**&q=**CITY**, **COUNTRY**&limit=1](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/346637838687298/?method=GET&path=search%3Ftype%3Dplace%26center%3D65.596586%2C22.153756%26q%3DLule%C3%A5%2C%20Sweden%26limit%3D1)

(You may have to add the **state** field for countries that use that division.)

Now you have a **Place ID** to use for your post.